# What makes a swimming pool lane "good"?

Tags: swimming

In his [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/This-Me-Autobiography-Ian-Thorpe/dp/1471101223), Ian Thorpe says:

> I had swum 1:49.16, the fifth-fastest heat time as it turned out. It meant I had a good lane in one of the semifinals later that night.

This begs the question: What makes a lane "good"?